# Databricks : java.io.IOException: Failed to perform getMountFileState(forceRefresh=true)

Tags: databricks

In Databricks I tried this :

```
storageName = "..."
accessKey = "..."
containerName = '...'

#try:
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://"+containerName+"\@"+storageName+".blob.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/foldername",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key."+storageName+".blob.core.windows.net": accessKey})
#except:
 # print("hello")
  #pass
```

And I had this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to perform &#39;getMountFileState(forceRefresh=true)&#39; for mounts after 3 attempts. Please, retry the operation.

Original exception: 'shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

What can I do to avoid this ?

Comment: do you have a longer stacktrace?

Comment: This ?
'Original exception: 'shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation'

Comment: is it Storage account access key, or SAS?

Comment: Storage account access key

Comment: I also have, in the logs of the cluster : Message DBFS is down.

Comment: `DBFS is down` is often produced when the driver is overloaded (for example if it's a shared cluster) - you may try to use driver node with more memory/CPUs